# php readfile wont read filename with inverted questionmark

Tags: php, path, readfile, file-exists

I have an example filename:  $filename = "./music/Daddy Yankee - ¿Qué Tengo Que Hacer.mp3"

When attempting to run `if (file_exists($filePathAudio)) {  }` returns file not found
Have confirmed that all other characters in string work properly except for this inverted question mark. How can I get the inverted mark to work, perhaps by some encoding % value?

The string for $filename is displayed by echo or log as the correct path, including all correctly named characters, but is thrown off by the mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably is the encoding per se. Try to use this sentence:

```
file_exists(mb_convert_encoding($filename, "UTF-8"));
```

Another option:

```
file_exists(iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $filename))
```

Comment: Thank you for helping with this! I am trying now to get the code you provided to work. So far, I still get the same not found error using these... I want to make sure it is not something hiding in my code, so I will make a new bank test php file and see if it works with only these lines.

Comment: Your answer did help! I has accidently added a space to the end of the filename when editing... Wow. But after fixing this and adding your example above ```file_exists(iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $filename))``` works perfectly! Thank you